# resubmit after refresh php page - why

Tags: php, submit, refresh, form-submit, page-refresh

resubmit after refresh php page - why

why?

i don't want resubmit after refresh!

any help?

i try more solution

but all solution is invalid!

this is my code,

if you have solution

please..

you edit my code to help me,

thanks.

this is my form code

```
<form id="uploadedfile" name="uploadedfile" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

this is upload.php code:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "zip", "pdf", "docx", "rar", "txt", "doc");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$newname = $extension.'_'.substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 7)), 4, 7);
$imglink = 'attachment/attachment_file_';
$uploaded = $imglink .$newname.'.'.$extension;
if ((($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "text/plain")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/x-zip-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "multipart/x-zip")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/x-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream"))
&& ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 5242880) // Max size is 5MB
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{   
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
$uploaded );
echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$uploaded.'">click</a>';
echo '<h3>'.$uploaded.'</h3>';
}
if($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] > 0){
echo '<h3>Please choose file to upload it!</h3>'; // If you don't choose file
}
elseif(!in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
echo '<h3>This extension is not allowed!</h3>'; // If you choose file not allowed
}
elseif($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] > 5242880){
echo "Big size!"; // If you choose big file
}
?>
```

Comment: can you add your form so we can see the action.

Comment: could you please explain a bit, we cant help you like this!

Comment: i edited it, see my form code

Answer (score 0):

Well,

After each form submit the post data remains in the session.
You can do after the script this way .

Method 1:

```
 unset($_POST);
 unset($_FILES);
 unset($_REQUEST);
```

Or , you ca do a

```
 header('Location:[YOUR URL]');
```

Where [YOUR URL] will be the url where you want to go after the file upload was processed.

after, so , the submitted data will not be preserved any more.